# Why doesn't these links work in IE7?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand why I cannot click the tags on top in IE7 on this website

It says javascript error but I debugged with Firefox and I don't get any error...

Could you give me some help ?

Comment: you can debug error by enabling debugger in IE7 too.

Comment: you can set follow. Tools->Internet Options…->Advanced->Disable Script Debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is where it crashes on IE :

```
document.getElementById("").SetReturnValue(__flash__toXML("http://www.sanstitre.ch/drupal/sites/default/files/files/projects/WM 1976/videos/P1030297.flv","460","345")) );
```

document.getElementById("") returns null

Comment: hi, I've solved. It was a bug of flash player in IE. IE need an ID for the embedding element object.

Comment: However, the links are still not working, so it wasn't because of javascript error...

Answer (score 1):

You can try debug this problem with Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038 or Fiddler tool (see http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which works as a proxy and can help also in the most of situation. At least you will see whether and what HTTP trafic IE send.

With fiddeler you will be able compare HTTP trafic in IE7 with the trafic in Firefox.